# GWT works great in Hosted Mode, and Compiles without error -- but its JS files are buggy

Tags: gwt

I have no errors show up in either the compilation or the hosted mode process, but the JS that GWT creates contain errors that disallow the proper rendering of the website. How can this happen? Is this a problem with the compiler?

FireBug is giving me nothing, no errors at all.

But I don't know where to go from here or what more information to give you all, since I can't effectively debug JS like this. More fundamentally, I just don't understand why GWT is giving me JS that doesn't work.

EDIT: I didn't really know what Pretty and Detailed meant until now. Thanks for pointing me to this. What I get now is https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIIQf.png.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

EDIT 2: Here is the final image I will post (I promise!): https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0bTt.png. This is the pretty output. The error reads: "Uncaught com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException (TypeError): Cannot call method 'isString' of null (anonymous function)."

Comment: What kind of errors? Have you tried using firebug, or something like it, to get more information?

Comment: "its JS files are buggy" and "contain errors" with no description of either makes this meaningless. You need to edit your question to provide more information about what "buggy" and "contain errors" mean, or it will most likely be closed for not being a real question.

Comment: I would recommend you to compile with the pretty flag, and debug the js code. There are differences between Dev & Web Mode: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html

Comment: See responses to your comments above, Ken and Luismahou.

Comment: Since your second image cut off the majority of the meaningful part of the error message, it's not very helpful. (You can't scroll a screen capture to see the part that overflows to the right.) "Cannot call method isString..." without the rest is pretty hard to trace from here. You might want to try and get a useful text capture to replace the image with to make it more useful. Otherwise, maybe you'll get lucky and someone here will have run across that exact problem without seeing any of your own code. Good luck. :)

Comment: Ken, the entire error message is reproduced below the code.

Comment: @Aaditya it's very difficult to see what's happening. If you debug your code in 'pretty' ('detailed' is too noisy) you should be able to know at which line of Java-equivalent code your application is failing.

Once you know which Java lines are causing the problem, you will be in a better position to solve your problem.

Comment: I have done this, @Luismahou, and am trying to actively debug right now. You can see the error message I have in my most recent edit.

Comment: Im getting the same problem, clearly I changed something that broke something, but I cant work out what...
`Uncaught com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot call method 'createStreamWriter' of null 9A9982E4DBDD20E56CDBFF3C6AB0E680.cache.html:6355
(anonymous function) 9A9982E4DBDD20E56CDBFF3C6AB0E680.cache.html:6355
gwtOnLoad 9A9982E4DBDD20E56CDBFF3C6AB0E680.cache.html:20291
maybeStartModule diarybooker.nocache.js:39
diarybooker.onScriptLoad diarybooker.nocache.js:227
(anonymous function) 9A9982E4DBDD20E56CDBFF3C6AB0E680.cache.html:20299`

Comment: Here is the "pretty" code, I cant work out from this where the jva equivalent line is:
`function entry_0(jsFunction){
  return function(){
    try {
      return entry0(jsFunction, this, arguments);
    }
     catch (e) {
      throw e;`
**Uncaught com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) : Cannot call method 'createStreamWriter' of null**
    `}
  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolution to this issue was the realization that isString was not a JNSI method, but instead a method I wrote in a try / catch block. This was the code that tripped me up:

```
try{something that will create a NullPointerException}
catch(NullPointerException npe){npe.printStackTrace()}
```

@Luismahou's link above said the following about error-catching in GWT:

> Exceptions: try, catch, finally and user-defined exceptions are supported as normal, although Throwable.getStackTrace() is not meaningfully supported in production mode.
>   Note: Several fundamental exceptions implicitly produced by the Java VM, most notably NullPointerException, StackOverflowError, and OutOfMemoryError, do not occur in production mode as such. Instead, a JavaScriptException is produced for any implicitly generated exceptions. This is because the nature of the underlying JavaScript exception cannot be reliably mapped onto the appropriate Java exception type.

I think what happened is that my try block threw a NullPointerException, which was represented as a JavaScriptException and was uncaught by the catch block. Lesson learned: don't catch NullPointerExceptions, StackOverflowErrors, and OutOfMemoryErrors in GWT.

Comment: If you need to catch a NullPointerException for some reason, then make sure that you catch both java.lang.NullPointerException and com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException.  You'll catch the first in hosted mode and the later in production mode.